# How do I start cycling in an array from the 2nd element using each? - Ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I have an array like this:

```
["auburn", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/web/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/cpg/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/eng/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/sof/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/sad/"]
```

What I would like to do is work on just the URLs in this array - which will always start at `element[1]` and go up.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This only shows the elements starting from 1 (the second element), -1 stands for the last element

```
a = ["auburn", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/web/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/cpg/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/eng/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/sof/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/sad/"] 

p a[1..-1]
=> ["http://auburn.craigslist.org/web/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/cpg/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/eng/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/sof/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/sad/"]
```

Answer (score 11):

```
a = ["auburn", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/web/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/cpg/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/eng/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/sof/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/sad/"]

a.drop(1).each { |m| puts m }

#=> http://auburn.craigslist.org/web/
#   http://auburn.craigslist.org/cpg/
#   http://auburn.craigslist.org/eng/
#   http://auburn.craigslist.org/sof/
#   http://auburn.craigslist.org/sad/
```

Comment: Will this always drop the first one? Also...I don't want it to remove the first element from the array....just temporarily not use it.

Comment: drop method returns a new array and does not affect the old one. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-drop

Comment: Interesting, it wasn't aware of #drop. That's a more readable approach than [1..-1].

Answer (score 3):

a[1..-1] will return the array with the first item removed.

Answer (score 2):

What about just simply choosing the elements you need:

```
a.grep(/^http:/).each { ... }
```

Or if you don't want new array copies to be created unnecessarily:

```
a.each { |e| 
  next if !e.match(/^http:/)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try **slice** :

```
arr = ["auburn", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/web/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/cpg/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/eng/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/sof/", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/sad/"]
arr.slice(1..-1)
```

**edit** :

use it like :

```
arr.slice(1..-1).each do |p|
  puts p
end
```

Comment: I am trying to do it in an `each`.

Comment: What's different between `slice` and just doing `[1..-1]`?